# Python: can view objects show keys of zombie dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here is my example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

myDict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
myKeys = myDict.keys()

# myDict = {} # toggle this line

myDict['y'] = 4

for myKey in myDict:
    print('D ' + myKey)
for myKey in myKeys:
    print('K ' + myKey)
```

If you run the program as shown here (with the line in the middle commented out), you get this output, which is exactly what I expected. The lines with the prefix `D` (loop over dictionary) have the same values as the lines with the prefix `K` (loop over keys of dictionary):

```
D a
D b
D c
D y
K a
K b
K c
K y
```

Now remove the hash and activate the line that was commented out. When you run the modified program, you get this:

```
D y
K a
K b
K c
```

But I expected one of these behaviors:

- either:
  After `myDict = {}` was executed, `myKeys` has become empty too (since it is a view object that always views the keys of its parent dictionary). Adding the item with the key `'y'` should result in this output:

```
   D y
   K y
```

- or: 
  After `myDict = {}` was executed, a new version of myDict was created and the previous version of myDict was destroyed, so `myKeys` has no longer any parent dictionary and therefor is pointing to null. So in this case looping over myKeys should throw an error.

But to me is looks as if the old version of myDict has become some kind of zombie, and myKeys is displaying the keys of this zombie.

---

So, here are my questions:

1. Is it true, that in my program myKeys shows keys of a zombie dictionary if the line in the middle is activated?
2. Is it reliable behavior, that myKeys will always show the keys of the previous version of the dictionary? (That would be very helpful for a program that I'm writing just now.)
3. Is there a way to revive the zombie dictionary? (I have all keys. Can I get the values too?)

Comment: "After myDict = {} was executed, myKeys has become empty too (since it is a view object that always views the keys of its parent dictionary). " No, `myKeys` has not become empty, since you never did anything to the dict it is acting as a view over. You simply re-assined the name, `myDict` to a *new, empty dict object*. The other dict is still alive and well, since there is at least one reference to it existing (the one in the keys_view object you created). However, that reference is not exposed externally, so unless you keep another reference to that dictionary around, you cannot access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental issue in your understanding here is that:

```
myDict = {}
```

Does *nothing* to the original `dict`, *assignment never mutates*, so the object that `myDict` was referring to is unmodified. Python objects will stay alive as long as something refers to them. CPython uses reference counting, and as an implementation detail, will reclaim objects *immediately* when their reference count reaches zero.

However, the `dict_keys` view object you created internally references the dictionary it is acting as a view over, so the original dictionary still has at least one reference to it, since the view object is alive. Note, though, the `dict_keys` API does not expose this reference, so if it is the only reference, you cannot really access your dict anymore (in any sane way).

> > Is it reliable behavior, that myKeys will always show the keys of the previous version of the dictionary?

You are misunderstanding the behavior. It is showing the keys of the same dictionary it has always been showing. There is *no previous dictionary*. The view is over the object, it doesn't care or know which variables happen to be referring to that object at any given time.

It's the same reason that if you do:

```
x = 'foo'
container = []
container.append(x)
x = 'bar'
print(container[0])
```

will still print "foo". Objects have no idea what names are referencing them at any given time, and should not care. And when one reference changes, the other references don't magically get updated.